# Single word meaning "freshness duration"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that encapsulates the phrases "freshness duration" or "duration until something is stale".

Comment: @tchrist That might work for cookies; it's less appropriate for biscuits.

Comment: TTL is what I settled on for lack of a better alternative @tchrist if you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @andrew I never mentioned anything about biscuits.

Comment: @windfold You never mentioned cookies, either.

Comment: Most people will not know what TTL means, FWIW. YMMV. 688 / TTFN.

Comment: @tchrist works for Transistor-Transistor Logic.

Comment: @Andrew Leach What's this "That might work for cookies; it's less appropriate for biscuits…", please?

Here in the UK, everyone I've ever heard say anything about them clearly thinks "biscuits" is a pure equivalent of US "cookies" but that would rule out what you said.

What are we missing? What difference do you see between "cookies" and "biscuits"?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin My comment followed tchrist's single link to TTL which preceded his answer by four hours. The difference between cookies and biscuits is that one is a computing term (which TTL would apply to) and one is not.

Comment: Oh, My Lord! See what I get for looking so hard at the trees, I didn't even notice there was a wood. Thanks Andrew.

Answer (score 8):

***Shelf-life*** seems to fit the bill.

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shelf%2Blife?region=uk&q=shelf-life) (as below) | [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/shelf-life) | [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/shelf-life)

> Definition of **shelf life**
>       *noun*
>           the length of time for which an item remains usable, fit for consumption, or saleable:
>               *the shelf life of fresh pasta*
>           *figurative*
>               *the new strategy will be lucky if it has a shelf life of more than a few months*

Answer (score 2):

Best before.
 Use by.
Expiry date.
 Use before.

Answer (score 0):

In programming we use TTL, meaning *time to live*, on packets, cookies, etc.

Comment: cookies have expiry, no TTL.TCP transport (packets) and DNS do have TTL. Although as the world has descended into madness and anarchy, some people do write very loosely about cookie TTL. Wikipedia article on TTL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live

Comment: Wiki citation from Chris can go into the answer.